# Trigger mousevents in table (via parent) with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, events, dynamic, html-table

I've got a problem and I don't get it:

I've got a table, each cell contains a small definition list and an anchor
so it would look like:

```
<table>
<tr>
    <td>
        <dl>
            <dt>Title</dt>
            <dd>Summary</dd>        
        </dl>
        <a>Link</a>
    <td>
</tr>
</table>
```

there are some more rows and colums but that should be enough :-)

What I want is to show the hidden (using .hide()-Method) anchor if the mouse enters the dl or perhaps the td. Plus hiding all other anchors contained in not 'mouseenter'ed td's / dl's.

I tried it with following function:

```
(function(){
    $('td').on('mouseenter', 'dl', function(){
        ($(this)
            .next());
            .show();
            .slideDown(300)
                .siblings('a')
                    .slideUp(300);

    })  
})();
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?
Could the problem be, that I create the tablecontent (tr's and downwards) dynamic during runtime?
I'm glad for any advice.

Comment: Is that your javascript? it has a typo you should have `$(function ...` instead of `(function ...`

Comment: Not necessarily. It looks like he's using a closure...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this should achieve what you want:

```
$(function() {  
    $('td').on('mouseenter', function() {  
        $(this).parents('table').find('a').slideUp(300);
        $(this).children('a').slideDown(300);
    });
});
```

See the jsFiddle here > http://jsfiddle.net/WR45L/.

Comment: wont work too... i tried to check if the event is triggerd via output on console... nothing happens (entering with mous - should trigger the function and write also to console.. nothing happens)

Comment: hmz... i have to observe something when building the table during runtime?

Comment: thx for help... just replacing the `on(...)` with `live(...)` for handling with dynamic created stuff - thx for ure advice @BenM :-)

Answer (score 0):

use:

```
$(this).parent().next().show().slideDown(300).siblings('a').slideUp(300);
```

Comment: just for general understanding: siblings here just works with the anchors in the same td?

Comment: yes, they will work match all anchors in the same td except the one we use siblings function on.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the javascript I've amended below. Looks like the code is wrong to me.

```
(function(){
    $('td').on('mouseenter', 'dt', function(){
        $(this)
            .next()
                .slideDown(300)
            .parent('dl')
                .siblings('a')
                    .slideUp(300);

    })  
})();
```

Comment: hm nope, doent work o-O, my fault, wont listen to the dt ... listen to the dl... changed it in up the code, but with no change o-O

Comment: Bit confused by what you are trying to achieve here. This code will slide up the `<a />` and slidedown the `<dd/>` since that is what it looks like you are trying to targer. If you are wanting to slide the anchor down in the hovered cell and slide it up in every other cell then @BenM 's solution will work. Alternatively you could change it so that the `mouseleave` event triggered the `<a />` `.slideup()`

Comment: my target is the last :-) slide up the anchor, when hovering over the belonging def-list, and hiding the anchors in all other table-elements sry for my ambiguous description =/